# How can I make angular-bootstrap datepicker accept 2 or 4 digit year input?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, angular-bootstrap

I've got a uib-datepicker-popup defined like this: `uib-datepicker-popup="M!/d!/yy"`

It works great except when I enter a 4 digit year. In that case, it seems to make my ng-model `undefined`. Is there any way to accept either a 4 digit year or a 2 digit year?

Comment: Can you please show us your code or what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uib-datepicker-popup="M!/d!/yyyy"
```

You have to choose the exact mask that you want, otherwise it will not update the model.

Answer (score 0):

in a slack conversation on Angular Buddies, I got word back from one of the authors of the angular-bootstrap datepicker code in question, and the answer is that feature (supporting both 'yy' and 'yyyy') is not supported. You have to pick one or the other. Recommended to use 'yyyy' so there is no chance of getting confused by the century, but the default century picked for 'yy' seems decent at least as of right now circa 2016.